# Issue with Multi-Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this two Methods

```
    public void L1Timer()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        int score = tot;
        Console.Write("Chances : " + ch);
        Console.CursorLeft = 40;
        Console.Write("Marks : " + score);
        for (int time = 0; time <= 100000; time++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 0);
            Console.Write("Time Elapsed : " + time + " Secs");
            Console.CursorLeft = 40;
            stime = time;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Beep();
            //Level1();
        }
    }

    public void Level1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.CursorLeft = 40;
        Console.WriteLine("C _ _ E _ _ _ T _ _ N");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        tot = 0;
        while ((tot <= 70) && (ch > 0))
        {
            Console.Write("Guess : ");
            string gues = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (gues)
            {
                case "E": tot += 10; ch--; L1Timer(); Level1(); break;
                case "L": tot += 10; ch--; break;
                case "B": tot += 10; ch--; break;
                case "R": tot += 10; ch--; break;
                case "A": tot += 10; ch--; break;
                case "I": tot += 10; ch--; break;
                case "O": tot += 10; ch--; break;
                default: tot += 0; ch--; break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

I want to Execute the first method first and then Start Executing the second with the first method timer still counting without delaying the Second Thread... I have tried this

```
            Thread T1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(L1Timer));

            Thread T2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Level1));

            T1.Start();

            T2.Start();
```

But it didn't work the way i want it..It excuted the first and second but took back the cursor to the first method which will not allow the user to type in the second method and answer the question...Pls help me out

Comment: You're inviting deadlocks by accessing the console from different threads.

Comment: Pls what can i do instead????

Comment: You should look into the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.  I had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890518/wpf-multithreaded-progress-dialog) in dealing with a WPF application that may help you.

Comment: Don't use `Console.ReadLine()`.  Instead, setup a main loop (all in the same thread...no need for different ones) that updates the time/score/etc, and checks for input using `Console.KeyAvailable` and `Console.ReadKey()`.

Comment: You shouldn't create a thread for your `L1Timer` method. Rather, you should create a `Timer` that fires once per second. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: @Idle_Mind Pls how do i do dat..Pls give example

Comment: @JimMischel Pls i dont understand...Pls can u explain further???

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea:
[image: Console Word Game Example]

Run it and watch the time elapsed in the upper right.  Hit some letters and check the score/chances.  Hit Escape then 'q' or 'r' and see what happens.

This is just a simple example to demonstrate the flow for a "fancy" console interface.  **I've put almost no real logic behind this "game" that you didn't already post in some fashion in your original question description; thus I don't consider this as "doing your homework for you."**   This is just "fluff" on top of a game.  A real assignment will probably have you put the game logic into a **Class**.  If you declare that class instance as static like I've done with the "Score" and "Chances" variables then the different routines besides Main() can access it and update the screen using values from your classes "game state".  Developing the Class to represent the Board and the current Game State is usually the core of the assignment and where your focus should really lie.

Hope it helps...

```
class Program
{

    static int Score = 0;
    static int Chances = 10;
    static int promptX, promptY;
    static string board = "{No Board Loaded}";
    static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
        Console.Title = "Some Word Game";

        bool quit = false;
        bool gameWon = false;
        bool gameOver = false;

        while (!quit)
        {
            Reset();
            ShowBoard("C _ _ E _ _ _ T _ _ N");

            gameWon = false;
            gameOver = false;
            while (!gameOver)
            {
                UpdateStats();

                // make it appear as though the cursor is waiting after the prompt:
                Console.SetCursorPosition(promptX, promptY);
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    cki = Console.ReadKey(true); // don't display key
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                    {
                        gameOver = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // if it's A thru Z...
                        if (char.IsLetter(cki.KeyChar)) 
                        {
                            string key = cki.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();
                            Console.Write(key);
                            switch (key)
                            {
                                case "E":
                                    Score += 10;
                                    Chances--;
                                    break;

                                case "L":
                                    Score += 10;
                                    Chances--;
                                    break;

                                case "B":
                                    Score += 10;
                                    Chances--;
                                    break;

                                case "R":
                                    Score += 10;
                                    Chances--;
                                    break;

                                case "A":
                                    Score += 10;
                                    Chances--;
                                    break;

                                case "I":
                                    Score += 10;
                                    Chances--;
                                    break;

                                case "O":
                                    Score += 10;
                                    Chances--;
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    Score += 0;
                                    Chances--;
                                    break;
                            }

                            // ... possibly update the board somehow in here? ... 
                            // ... some board logic ...
                            // ShowBoard("updated board in here");

                            // set gameOver to drop out of loop
                            // also set gameWon if the user beat the board

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write(" ");
                        }

                    }
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }

            if (gameWon)
            {
                // ... do something ...
            }
            else
            {
                // ... do something else ...
            }

            quit = QuitProgram();
        }
    }

    static void Reset()
    {
        // reset game variables and clock:
        Score = 0;
        Chances = 10;
        SW.Restart();

        Console.Clear();
        CenterPrompt("Guess: ");
        promptX = Console.CursorLeft;
        promptY = Console.CursorTop;
    }

    static void ShowBoard(string NewBoard)
    {
        board = NewBoard;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth / 2 - board.Length / 2, promptY - 2);
        Console.Write(board);
    }

    static void UpdateStats()
    {
        // hide cursor while we update the stats:
        Console.CursorVisible = false;

        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.Write("Score: " + Score.ToString("000"));

        Console.SetCursorPosition(35, 0);
        Console.Write("Chances: " + Chances.ToString("00"));

        TimeSpan ts = SW.Elapsed;
        string totalTime = String.Format("Time Elapsed: {0}:{1}:{2}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes.ToString("00"), ts.Seconds.ToString("00"));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth - totalTime.Length, 0);
        Console.Write(totalTime);

        // ... add other output statistics in here? ...

        // turn cursor back on for the prompt:
        Console.CursorVisible = true;
    }

    static void CenterPrompt(string message)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth / 2 - message.Length / 2, Console.WindowHeight / 2);
        Console.Write(message);
    }

    static bool QuitProgram()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        CenterPrompt("Thanks for playing! Press 'q' to Quit, or 'r' to Retry.");
        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                switch (cki.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper())
                {
                    case "Q":
                        return true;

                    case "R":
                        return false;

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but when i run the app, the timer wasn't counting

Comment: Not sure what you did wrong.  Did you start with a **new, blank** Console project and paste this code over it?